# Serviceworker must be a dictionary in your web app manifest

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, razorpay

I had done payment integration to razorpay and when click the button it throws an console error serviceworker must be a dictionary.

Comment: I have got the same error while in testing mode of Razorpay. Did you know why?

Comment: i too getting this error in live mode

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this ?

Comment: same issue for me too. I was testing Google Pay Integrations and i was getting this error. Have added ServiceWorker in manifest file as well. Still no luck

Comment: anybody has a fix for this ?

Comment: got the same issue as well...in test mode

Comment: Can you show the manifest? Also [these guys](https://nithinkvarrier.in/razorpay-integration-with-vue-js-and-nuxt-js/) seem to have solved the issue. I dont have time to read this and distill it into an answer but it might help.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue while integrating razor-pay. Please share the  fix, if anyone has found for it.

Comment: Guys, please share the code of your app so we can finger out what's wrong.

Comment: @AkshayBarpute share your manifest file. and also tell me why you are using a service worker?

Comment: @Sujay  share your manifest file. and also tell me why you are using a service worker?

Comment: @Yohanelly share your manifest file. and also tell me why you are using a service worker?

Comment: @RohitNishad People are using service workers because their app deems it important for updates, changes, or maybe it's there in whatever framework they are using.

Comment: @bhaskar you face this issue? give me more info about it, share your manifest file.

Answer (score 6):

This is an error coming from `razorpay.js` file. You can simply ignore this and you will be able to integrate any flow without an issue. I have recently integrated this and it is working fine in the production.

Comment: seems cancelling razorpay popup doesnt disables the overlay... any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Varun did you ever find a solution to this issue as I am facing the same and trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

This question is abstract and it does not provide the least code to reproduce the issue, therefore it is difficult to tell where the error message comes from. This [example](https://nithinkvarrier.in/razorpay-integration-with-vue-js-and-nuxt-js) shows how it basically works.

Answer (score 0):

add this checkout.js file inside body tag.
it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).